# Pattern matching never terminates

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this javascript for pattern matching. When I open the HTML file and the scripts run, it never ends. The page loads forever. The logs inside the `if` and `else` never print out. I am unable to find the problem.

```
var link="https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=EUtVWuX5JpGRkwWW_py4Cg&q=testing+for+schools&oq=testing&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0i131k1j0l9.7269.8065.0.9955.7.7.0.0.0.0.175.755.4j3.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.754...0i3k1.0.TglIEkPkeIU";
var pattern = "(https:\\/\\/)(.*\\.)*(google.co.uk)(\\/.*)*(\\/)*";

if(link.search(pattern) == 0)
    {
        console.log("inside if");
        console.log("Match");

    }
else
    {
        console.log("inside else");
        console.log("Not Match");
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
I need a RegEx that represents almost any URL starts with https. The only thing that is variable is the domain name, e.g. google.co.uk. I thought my RegEx was perfect but it could not handle this case.

**EDIT2:**
The logic for the patter I need is: `(any-sub-domain.)*(domain-name)(/something)* (/)*`

```
EDIT3:
```

Sorry the previous edit corrected now. It was wrong because I did not put it in code.

Comment: `(\\/.*)*` is probably not doing what you think it's doing. Also, any reason you're using so many capturing groups? If all you want to do is match a URL starting with `https` and a particular domain, why not just use `https:\\/\\/google\.co\.uk\\/.*`?

Comment: `(\\/.*)*` does not this convey: optionally (backslash that is optionally followed by any character repeated any number of times)?

Comment: My patters is not only for google. also, there are sub domains I try to capture. The sub-domains can be more than one sub-domain. Also the `/.` at the end can be repeated multiple times.

Comment: Can you give examples with expected results/matches?

Comment: If you want to capture something, why do you use `String.prototype.search` that only returns the index of the match? Also if you want to understand what happens (and other things), read [that](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: You may use [`/(https:\/\/)([^\/.]*\.)*(google\.co\.uk)(\/[^\/]*)*(\/*)/`](https://regex101.com/r/NfFUek/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a regex to parse the whole URL, I suggest first using the [`URL` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) of JavaScript to extract the relevant parts of the URL. Then you can check attributes of the URL such as `hostname` and `protocol` using `if`:

```js
var link = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=EUtVWuX5JpGRkwWW_py4Cg&q=testing+for+schools&oq=testing&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0i131k1j0l9.7269.8065.0.9955.7.7.0.0.0.0.175.755.4j3.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.754...0i3k1.0.TglIEkPkeIU";
var urlObject = new URL(link);

console.log(urlObject.hostname); // "www.google.co.uk"
console.log(urlObject.protocol); // "https:"

if (urlObject.protocol === "https:") {
    if (urlObject.hostname.endsWith('google.co.uk')) {
        console.log("this page is on Google UK");
    } else {
        console.log("this page is on some other HTTPS web site");
    }
} else {
    console.log("this page is not secured by HTTPS");
}
```

Comment: I posted that example for simplicity. But it more complex. I prefer RegEx.

Comment: after several attempts, I think your idea solution the safest.